# Condition notation: all variables must all be zero or all not be zero

Tags: notation

To be or not to be...

What is a good mathematical notation of the criterion, that all variables in an equation must all be zero (or whatever value) or all not be zero (or whatever value)?

On the internet I couldn't find anything that would answer my question. Example of what I think it would look like:
$$y = f(x, u, i)$$
$$x, u, i \neq 0 \text{ or } x, u, i = 0$$

Hope to hear from you.

Comment: You can write $(x,u,i)=(0,0,0)$ or $(x,u,i)\neq(0,0,0)$. In general, if you have $(x_1,…,x_n)\in E^n$ where $0\in E$, you can write $(x_1,…,x_n)=(0,…,0)$ or $(x_1,…,x_n)\neq(0,…,0)$.

Comment: @DankaMakabre $(x,u,i)=(1,0,0)\neq(0,0,0)$ but these $x,u,i$ do not satisfy the requirements.

Comment: My bad, I understood all zeroes or some non-zero. Then, $x_1,…,x_n\neq0$ seems pretty standard.

Comment: In some cases, for example multi-indices, you'd use the notation $\vert a \vert = a_1 + \cdots + a_n$. Then your condition would be 'either $\vert a\vert = 0$ or $\vert a\vert > 1$.'

Comment: @DankaMakabre, would you suggest it to be 'Either 1,…, ≠ 0 or 1,…, = 0'

Answer (score 3):

"Either $x,u,i$ are all zero or none of them is zero."

Alternatively, "Either $x=u=i=0$ or $xui\neq0.$"
But I think this is not as clear as simply saying what you mean.

Not everything has to be a notation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I agree that saying what you mean is clearer. I also like Danka's second answer.